# SharePoint WSP Deployment Best Practices

Tags: deployment, solution-package, iis

I'm building a few WSPs (a custom web part and a branding wsp both scoped to site collection level) using WSP builder on VS2010.  Our SharePoint 2007 Farm contains two Web applications.

I'd like to know whether deployment of a WSP to a particular web application (Web App A) will only recycle the application pool for that given web application (Web App A). And that the other web application (Web App B) would be unaffected during this process.

What I want to ensure is users of the other web application won't experience any down time in anyway during this release and that the wsp appears only in one Web App when viewing the site collection features lists.

Does this type of deployment only cause app pool recycling or does IIS get reset too?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App pools are per site collection and so any web sites under that collection will get a connection reset.

IIS reset does not occur.

regards,
KS